# JAVA GIS method not behaving as expected

Tags: java, esri, coordinate-transformation

I am using a method call to transform a Point in one spatial reference to another (one coordinate plane to another basically) and the call works fine in the first example, then in the second example I am using the same method on the same object type and the method has no effect on the Point... code and an example below: (the midpoint.project(GeometryUtil.getLatLongCoordSystem)) is the method call I am having issues with)

```
//works fine...

if (closestStationOrSpanFw != null) {
                IGeometry shape = closestStationOrSpanFw.getIFeature().getShapeCopy();
                Point point = null;
                if (shape instanceof Point) {
                    point = (Point) shape;
                    System.out.println("OLD POINT coords: " + point.getX() + "        " + point.getY());
                    point.project(GeometryUtil.getLatLongCoordSystem());
                    System.out.println("NEW POINT coords: " + point.getX() + "        " + point.getY());


//Problem code:

else if (shape instanceof Polyline){
                    Polyline line = (Polyline) shape;
                    Point lowerLeft = (Point) line.getEnvelope().getLowerLeft();
                    Point upperRight = (Point) line.getEnvelope().getUpperRight();
                    Point midpoint = GeometryUtil.getMidpoint(lowerLeft, upperRight);
                    System.out.println("OLD LINE coords: " + midpoint.getX() + "        " + midpoint.getY());
                    midpoint.project(GeometryUtil.getLatLongCoordSystem());
                    System.out.println("NEW LINE coords: " + midpoint.getX() + "        " + midpoint.getY());
```

output of the properly working Point System.outs:

```
OLD POINT coords: 1860356.9240645461        1698342.0271777364
NEW POINT coords: -87.85965314497173        34.6678477163251
```

output of the broken Polyline System.outs (very close to point coordinate above):

```
OLD LINE coords: 1860490.636483086        1698315.1646775191
NEW LINE coords: 1860490.636483086        1698315.1646775191
```

As you can see, this seems to work properly in the first case but not in the second. Any ideas?

Comment: Is Point a final class? Could it be that the line method returns you a different runtime type that re-implements the project method?

Comment: how is midpoint defined in the first example?

Comment: @Diego it doesn't appear so when setting breakpoints in each of the aboce vlasses and calling .getClass() on them, they both return com.esri.arcgis.geometry.Point

Comment: That's odd. I have no experience with the library in particular, but the only guess I can think of is that the second point is already in that coordinate system (which definitely doesn't look like). Depending on your IDE, you can probably breakpoint inside the .project method and then go step-by-step and see what's the difference between the two scenarios

Comment: @Diego yes, unfortunately they are decompiled class files so it's awfully difficult to make sense of what is going on in them

Comment: @epoch excuse the typo, that existed only in my SO post, not my actual code :D

Comment: The doc says "To Project, the geometry needs to have a Spatial Reference set, and not have an UnknownCoordinateSystem. The new spatial reference system passed to the method defines the output coordinate system. If either spatial reference is Unknown, the coordinates are not changed. The Z and measure values are not changed by the Project method." . Are those conditions met in the second case? (ref: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/ArcObjects/esrigeometry/IGeometry_Project.htm)

Comment: @Diego this was the issue! it is now working after setting a spatial reference on my point before passing to teh project method. If you would like to post as answer I will happily upvote/accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/ArcObjects/esrigeometry/IGeometry_Project.htm) states that "to Project, the geometry needs to have a Spatial Reference set, and not have an UnknownCoordinateSystem. The new spatial reference system passed to the method defines the output coordinate system. If either spatial reference is Unknown, the coordinates are not changed. The Z and measure values are not changed by the Project method"

Your second point probably doesn't have a spatial reference set. Setting it should fix it.